# Segmentation fault while converting infix to postfix

Tags: c, data-structures

I am converting infix to postfix, here is my code, can anyone please figure out why i am getting the segmentation fault?
Why i am getting the segmentation fault ? Please explain. I tried that multiple times still i am getting the same thing. Please help.

Is it because i took excess memory or what? or my program is taking too much time to execute?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100
char infix[MAX],postfix[MAX];
int top = -1;
char stack[MAX];

void push(char element){
    if(top == MAX-1)
        {
        printf("Error: Stack Overflow\n");
        }
    else
        {
            top = top +1;
            stack[top] = element;
        }
}

char pop(){
    if (top == -1)
        printf("Error: Stack Underflow\n");
    else
        {
            return stack[top];
            top = top -1;
        }
}

int precedence(char symbol){

    switch(symbol){

        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 2;
            break;
        case '*':
        case '/':
        case '%':
            return 3;
            break;
        case '(':
        case ')':
        case '#':
            return 1;
            break;
        default: 
            return 0;
            break;
    }
}

void infixtopostfix(char infix[],char postfix[]){

    int i=0,j=0;
    char symbol;
    stack[++top] = '#';

    for (i=0;i<strlen(infix);i++){

        symbol = infix[i];

        if(isalnum(symbol)){
            postfix[j] = symbol;
            j++; 
        }
        else if (symbol == '('){
            push(symbol);
        }
        else if (symbol == ')'){

            while(stack[top] != '('){
                postfix[j] = pop();
                j++;
            }
            pop();     //This will pop out ( from the stack.
        }
        else{
            if (precedence(symbol)>stack[top]){
                push(symbol);
            }
            else{
                while(precedence(symbol)<=stack[top]){
                    postfix[j] = pop();
                    j++;
                }
                push(symbol);
            }
        }
    }

    while(stack[top] != '#'){

        postfix[j] = pop();
        j++;
    }
    postfix[j] = '\0';
}

void main(){


    printf("Enter an infix expression:\t");
    scanf("%s",infix);

    infixtopostfix(infix,postfix);
    printf("The infix expression is:  %s",infix);
    printf("The postfix expression is: %s",postfix);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Or plenty of "printf" to see where it crash. Likely some index out of bounds.

Comment: `return stack[top];
            top = top -1;` -  See a problem here?

Comment: `void main()` - illegal signature -> undefined behaviour.

Comment: @EugeneSh.Thanks, that was a major bug!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have not taken a close look at your code, just a cursory glance.

Your pop() function is not well-formed.

```
    if (top == -1)
    printf("Error: Stack Underflow\n");
else
    {
        return stack[top];
        top = top -1;
    }
```

1) I am pretty sure this will not even compile (or at least your C compiler will throw some errors) because if top == -1, then this function will not even return anything.
2) The function returns before updating "top". This means that the top decrement never actually happens, so stack is continually indexed by "top".

This may not be the direct cause of your seg fault, but it is a good starting point. As a general suggestion in spirit with that of @Ripi2, I suggest you debug this code either with a debugger (i.e. GDB), printf statements, or a memory profiler such as valgrind.

Comment: The first (1) of these points is the reason any stack implementations worth their salt do *not* return values from `pop()`; they provide access to them via a `top()` mechanic, then the caller `pop()` s afterward. And *neither* is done by the caller if a `empty()` mechanic indicates the stack has no content. Regarding your (2) point, take solace, that is precisely why `while(stack[top] != '#')` runs to infinity, and eventually `postfix` is overrun with the same content over and over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

**MAJOR -->** You forgot to pass `stack[top]` as argument to `precedence` function while comparing `precedence` values.

call `pop()` function only when there is some element present in stack - better make `top` represent the no. of elements currently present in stack (initialize it with *0* rather than **-1**.

**IMP-->** In `pop()` function (or any other function), once the `return` statement has been executed after that you cannot modify `top=top-1` --> better make it `return stack[--top]`.

---

Here is the correct code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<ctype.h>
  #include<string.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #define MAX 100
  char infix[MAX],postfix[MAX];
  int top = 0;
  char stack[MAX];

  void push(char element){
      if(top == MAX-1)
      {
          printf("Error: Stack Overflow\n");
      }
      else
      {
        stack[top++] = element;
      }
 }

 char pop(){
      if (top ==1)
          printf("Error: Stack Underflow\n");
      else
      {  
        return stack[--top];
      }
  }

  int precedence(char symbol){
        printf("pre%d\n\n",symbol);
        if((symbol=='+')||(symbol=='-')
                  return 1;
        if((symbol=='*')||(symbol=='/')||(symbol=='%'))
                 return 2;
        else
                 return 0;
   }

    void infixtopostfix(char infix[],char postfix[]){

         int i=0,j=0;
         char symbol;
         stack[++top] = '#';

         for (i=0;i<strlen(infix);i++){

          symbol = infix[i];
          if(isalnum(symbol)){
               postfix[j] = symbol;
               j++; 
          }
          else if (symbol == '('){
               push(symbol);
          }
          else if (symbol == ')'){
               while(stack[top] != '('){
                    postfix[j] = pop();
                    j++;
           }
               pop();     //This will pop out ( from the stack.
           }
           else{
            while((top>1)&&(precedence(symbol)<=precedence(stack[top-1]))){
                postfix[j] = pop();
                j++;
           }
               push(symbol);
        }
    }

    while(top>1){

        postfix[j] = pop();
        j++;
    }
    postfix[j] = '\0';
 }

int main(){


    printf("Enter an infix expression:\t");
    scanf(" %s",infix);

    infixtopostfix(infix,postfix);
    printf("The infix expression is:  %s",infix);
    printf("The postfix expression is: %s",postfix);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. I did a major mistake by not taking it as precedence(stack[top]). And yup even that return statement thing.

Comment: I thinh taking as -1 is fine as when i am pushing i first say top = top + 1, so this works well. Thanks a lot anyways :)

Comment: It was indeed helpful. Thanks again :)